# Adding rows to DataGridView in VB.NET

Tags: .net, winforms, datagridview

I have a DataGridView set up with the following columns:

Teacher, Subject, Date, Period.

After a lot of Googleing I can see there are a few ways to add data to the grid programmatically, with each one differing to another quite extensively.

I wanted your opinion on how I should go about this, considering I am going to be adding data from a text file line-by-line (using ":" as a delimiter) and I want each line to have its own row, so it's going to be in a loop.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since the data in the text file is delimited then one way to do this is to use the *Split* function to create an array of cell strings and then just add these directly to the grid.

```
Dim CellData() As String
Dim LineText As String = ""

' open the data file
Dim objReader As New System.IO.StreamReader("c:\temp\file.dat")

Do While objReader.Peek() <> -1
    LineText = objReader.ReadLine()
    ' split the line of text into cells
    CellData = Split(LineText, ":")
    Me.DataGridView1.Rows.Add(CellData)
Loop
```